# Canonical expansion of a structure

Tags: model-theory

Fixed a signature $\tau = (I,J,K,ar)$ and a $\tau -structure$ $A$, the canonical expansion of $A$ by a $B$ (where $B$ is a subset of the universe of $A$) is the structure where the elements of $B$ are new constant symbols. 
I understand the concept formally but I cannot find out a concrete example. 
About the reduction of a structure in a smaller language, I can visualize the concept as a forgetful functor e.g. from a ring to a grou. Is there a way to visualize the canonical expansion likewise?

Comment: What's the problem with coming up with examples? Pick your favorite structure and any subset of that structure and name the elements of that subset by constants. For example, you could take the rational order $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ and name the integers by new constant symbols. Or you could take the complex field and name $i$ by a constant symbol.

Comment: Ok, i understand the concept, but what's the use? I already have those constants in the universe of the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question in the comments: "What's the use?"

Let's say $M$ is a $\tau$-structure, and $A\subseteq M$. Then we can form a new signature $\tau_A$ by adding a new constant symbol for each element of $A$ and view $M$ is a $\tau_A$-structure $M_A$.

The basic reason to do this is that whenever $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a $\tau$-formula and $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is a tuple from $A$, we can view $\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ as a $\tau_A$-sentence. So if we let $T_A = \text{Th}_{\tau_A}(M_A)$ and $T = \text{Th}_\tau(M)$, then $T_A$ contains $T$ together with the full type / elementary diagram of $A$: $$T_A = T\cup \{\varphi(\overline{a})\mid \overline{a}\in A\text{ and }M\models \varphi(\overline{a})\}.$$ In other words, a model of $T_A$ is a model $N\models T$, together with a specified subset realizing the type of $A$, or equivalently a specified partial elementary map $A\to N$. And a $\tau_A$-elementary embedding $N\to N'$ between two models of $T_A$ is a $\tau$-elementary embedding which preserves the copy of $A$.

A typical application is this: Let's say you want to use a compactness argument to find an elementary extension of a structure $M$ with certain properties. It's not enough to find a model $N\models T$ satisfying these properties, since there might not be an elementary embedding of $M$ into $N$. But if we expand the language by constants for $M$ (taking $A = M$ in the above discussion), then every model of $T_M$ has a specified elementary embedding of $M$, so it's enough to use your compactness argument to find a model of $T_M$ satisfying your properties.

You ask about a "functorial" view. Like any expansion, there will be a reduct / "forgetful" functor from the category of models of $T_A$ to the category of models of $T$. Unlike in universal algebra (groups, rings, etc.), where free constructions abound, there is unlikely to be a nice functor in the other direction, from models of $T$ to models of $T_A$. But if you like category theory, you can think about the category of models of  $T_A$ as being a vast generalization of the category of [pointed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set): An object of this category is an object of the base category (sets / models of $T$) with extra structure (a choice of base point / a choice of copy of $A$), though not every object in the base category admits such structure (e.g. the empty set / a structure which doesn't realize the type of $A$). And the morphisms are restricted to those which preserve the extra structure.

Alternatively, the category of substructures of models of $T_A$ and partial elementary maps is the coslice category over $A$ of the category of substructures of models of $T$ and partial elementary maps.

For a concrete example of this point about restricting morphisms: In the field language, $\mathbb{C}$ has an automorphism sending $i$ to $-i$. In fact, the subfield fixed by all automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$. If we add a constant symbol for $i$ to the language, then any automorphism of $\mathbb{C}_{\{i\}}$ fixes $i$, and the subfield fixed by all automorphisms of this structure is $\mathbb{Q}[i]$.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's really helpful